# Padding between images when items are divs with background images

Tags: html, css

I've got a bunch of divs with background images like this:

```
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

...and so on (there are 20+ divs).

Each div has it's own background image.

Right now, on large screens I want to display 3 divs per line so I've got this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  div {
    width:33%;
  }   
}
```

What I would like is a 'gutter' that is 2ch wide between each div. When I use `padding:2ch;` it doesn't work (no space between divs) and when I use `margin:2ch;` then the 3rd div goes down to the next line (even with `box-sizing:border-box`).

What's the simplest solution to this? Here's an example of what I want the divs to look like (see each class image: http://www.platinumfitnessaz.com/classes/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have your CSS available?

Comment: Use padding:2%; or margin:2%; use porcentage instead ch

Comment: Either use percentage like Risa said, or look into the `calc()` feature of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to comments, percentage vs `ch` units has nothing to do with it. It's just the fact that you don't have enough room to fit things in a row.

If your page is `100%` wide, then 3 divs in a row that are `33%` wide will of course not leave any room for a margin. `box-sizing` only affects padding and borders, not margins, so that won't help you.

The solution is to use a `calc()` function.

If you want a `2ch` space around your divs, use `2ch` as the *margin*. Then, if you want three per row, you can use `calc(33% - 2ch)` to get the width of each one.

We only really need a right and bottom margin to achieve the effect you want:

```css
div {
  width: calc(33.333% - 2ch);
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2ch;
  margin-right: 2ch;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

That's the simple version. It doesn't fully maximize our space, though, because there's a `2ch` margin on the right of the third column of divs that could be reapportioned to the divs themselves.

To fully make use of all the space, we can do a little math to make our calc expressions a bit fancier, and then use `nth-child` to only apply the right margin to the divs in the first and second column:

```css
div {
  width: calc(calc(calc(calc(33.333% - 2ch) * 2) + 33.333%) / 3);
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2ch;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
div:nth-child(3n+1),
div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-right: 2ch;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```